# codeigniter custom library does not load

Tags: codeigniter, autoload

I am a total beginner with codeigniter and been trying to make a custom library that I have written to be loaded. I have set CI to start the website by a controller called 'check_login'.
The contents of this file are as follows:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Check_login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct (){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('check_login');
    }

    function index (){
        $this->check_login->checker();
    }
}
```

The library 'check_login' is been put in `CI/application/libraries/` and contains the following script:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Check_Login {
    public function cheker (){
        //$CI =& get_instance();
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }      
    }

}
```

I have also tried using `$CI =& get_instance();` instead of `$this`, and also tried adding the name of the library to the `autoload config` file to see if it works. The result that the browser displays is as follows:
[The Output in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1DLA.png)
I would like to know what causes my library not to load, and when I should use `get_instance();` instead of $this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have also viewed the link below but I can't understand anything:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250061/codeigniter-custom-library-not-loading

Comment: you can't load view in library from library just return the $is_logged_in and use this if cogitation in your controller.

Comment: Not sure if this could help, but your controller and library shares the same name, have you tried changing your controller name? Could confuse the system when trying to load those classes

Comment: And your function is named "cheker" instead of "checker"...

Comment: Thanks to your guides I no more receive any errors but the result is a blank page. Could you tell me how to pass $is_logged_in to the controller?.

Comment: just use return $is_logged_in;

Comment: Dear Yaseen, I know it is annoying to ask this but I can't find it anywhere. I don't know how to use the returned data in the controller? neither it gets echoed nor print_r is useful.

Comment: let ma give you an example 

this code in your controller.

$result = $this->library->example_function();
echo $result;

this code in your library.

public function example_function(){
        return 123123;
    }
try it you will know what i'm asking.

Comment: You can't have controller and library both with same name. Change one file/class name and try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I know very little about PHP. I had been calling the library without assigning its value in a variable. Therefore, in the index function of the controller I should change the command to:
`$q = $this->check_login->checker();echo $q;`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your class name to `Check_login` or something other with lower case. And you are calling `$this->check_login->checker();` where as in your library your function name is `cheker()`

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Check_login {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();   
    }
    public function cheker ()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }      
}
```

Why **$CI =& get_instance();** 
Assigning by reference allows you to use the original CodeIgniter object rather than creating a copy of it.